# How to connect midi device to grandMA2 encoders?

Tags: macros, console, midi

I have a midi controller with 3 rotary encoders and I want to connect them to grandMA2 onPC software. I know how to setup midi remotes and stuff, but it doesn't allow you to connect to the encoder wheels.

I'm running all my midi thru [Midi-ox](http://www.midiox.com/) software in combination with [loopMidi](https://www.tobias-erichsen.de/software/loopmidi.html).

So how can I map the real encoders to virtual ones? Without using ShowCockpit?

Answer (score 0):

First, there are multiple tutorials online already. The best way would definitely be ShowCockpit, but I get that it can get pricey... The alternative I found does not work perfectly, but it works.

1. make the output of your encoder note A (not as musically A but like ANY note) when turned clockwise and note B when turned counterclockwise. This can be done easily in Bomes Midi but very similarly you can do it in Midi-OX using maps.
2. in grandMA onPC you make a macro for clockwise and counter-clockwise rotation for each of you're encoders that goes like this - `Feature $feature.1 At + $resolution1` where `$feature` automatically returns the selected menu like Gobo1, Dimmer, Position, etc. `.1` is the first virtual encoder (.2 is the second...) and that it adds to that attribute whatever is stored in the `$resolution1` variable. Now assign this macro to the clockwise rotation of your first encoder. For counter-clockwise its the same macro but you flip the `+` to a -
3. We have to setup the $resolution1 variable to whatever you decide, but I recommend making a macro that cycles it from 10, then 1 and last 0.1. Command for that is `SetVar $resolution1 = 10`

For the other encoders you just alter the numbers and that is it.